# duplicate acceptance of the same socket connection request in Java

Tags: java, android, http

I am implementing a simple http server using Java `ServerSocket`, on Android 6.1 platform. By calling `ServerSocket.accept()`, the thread is blocking until request comes in.

The problem is, I always saw duplicate acceptances of the same http request, and eventually only one of them could get contents of the request. Any idea?

A simple http server using Java ServerSocket, on Android 6.1 platform

```java
while (mServerSocket != null && !mServerSocket.isClosed()) {
    try {
        Log.i(TAG, "{\"msgid\":\"RunningServer\",\"msg\":\"LogHttpServer starts to listen at " + mServerSocket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress() + ":" + mServerSocket.getLocalPort() + "\"}");
        Socket clientSocket = mServerSocket.accept();
        Thread clientRequest = new WorkThread(clientSocket, appContext);
        clientRequest.start();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        ...
    }
}

class WorkThread extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
    Log.i(TAG, "{\"msgid\":\"ReceivingData\",\"msg\":\"LogHttpServer accepted connection from "+socket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress()+"\"}");
    processHttpRequest(this.socket);

    private void processHttpRequest(Socket socket) {
        BufferedReader in = null;
        OutputStream out = null;

        if (this.socket.isConnected()) {
            try {
                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "{\"msgid\":\"IOException\",\"msg\":\"fail to get Input Stream, " + e.toString() + "\"}");
            }

            try {
                out = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "{\"msgid\":\"IOException\",\"msg\":\"fail to get Input Stream, " + e.toString() + "\"}");
            }

            int lineNum = 0;
            String method = null;
            String request = null;

            while (true) {
                String line;
                try {
                    if ( in == null || (line = in.readLine()) == null || line.length() == 0) break;
                    lineNum++;

                    Log.i(TAG, "{\"msgid\":\"HttpRequest\",\"msg\":\"" + line + "\"}");
                    line = line.trim();
                    if (lineNum == 1) {
                        StringTokenizer tokenized = new StringTokenizer(line);
                        method = tokenized.hasMoreTokens() ? tokenized.nextToken().toUpperCase() : null;
                        request = tokenized.hasMoreTokens() ? tokenized.nextToken().toLowerCase() : null;
                    }

               } catch (IOException e) {
                   Log.e(TAG, "{\"msgid\":\"IOException\",\"msg\":\"fail to read in Stream\"}");
               } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "{\"msgid\":\"Exception\",\"msg\":\"" + e.toString() + "\"}");
                    return;
               }

           }
           ...
     }
}
```

The resulting logs show as below:

```
2019-06-14T10:34:52.635Z  3149  3209 I LogHttpServer: {"msgid":"RunningServer","msg":"LogHttpServer starts to listen at :::33284"}
2019-06-14T10:34:52.636Z  3149  3209 I LogHttpServer: {"msgid":"RunningServer","msg":"LogHttpServer starts to listen at :::33284"}
2019-06-14T10:34:52.636Z  3149  4409 I LogHttpServer: {"msgid":"ReceivingData","msg":"LogHttpServer accepted connection from 192.168.43.254"}

--> this is where I don't expect: duplicate acceptance with separate thread created.
2019-06-14T10:34:52.636Z  3149  4410 I LogHttpServer: {"msgid":"ReceivingData","msg":"LogHttpServer accepted connection from 192.168.43.254"} 

2019-06-14T10:34:52.642Z  3149  4409 I LogHttpServer: {"msgid":"HttpRequest","Method":"GET", "Request":"/cgi-bin/logs.sh"}

--> later, it actually not able to parse the contents
2019-06-14T10:35:03.216Z  3149  4410 E LogHttpServer: {"msgid":"InvalidHttpRequest","msg":"null Method or Request. Return."}
```

Comment: There is no evidence here of accepting the same *connection* twice, let alone the same request. If you logged the remote port as well as the remote address you would see that. And there is no code here at all that logs the final two messages.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

I used sniffer to check http request sent into the air, and indeed only one was seen. And in the logs, two threads (4409 and 4410) were spawned to process incoming request. I think it is pretty evident? 

On the other hand, I did not put all of the codes. I will. But basically, it is parsing of http request, and by checking the thread ID, we can see the 4409 was correctly parsed and 4410 has null "method" or "request" field in the header.

Comment: It's not evident at all. As what you claim is impossible, you need to make an effort to provide credible evidence, *here.* You need to post a log showing the remote IP address *and port* being *equal*, as I stated two days ago. And also you can't possibly read the same data from the same socket twice: and the fact that the second request didn't parse proves it was different from the first. And where and how is `this.socket` defined? You need to provide *complete* code, sufficient for someone else to execute it.